# Add methods to Func

Tags: c#, list, func

I have a list of Func and I want to add elements.
If I add them on Start like below, no problem:

```
        public List<System.Func<bool>> conditions = new List<System.Func<bool>>();

        void Start()
        {
        conditions.Add(Iamdead);
        conditions.Add(Iamalive);
        }

        bool Iamdead()
        {
        ...
        return ...;
        }
        bool Iamalive()
        {
        ...
        return ...;
        }
```

But I want to define the list without Start so that I have a clean list of methods that I can see as elements in a row. I have tried the classic format:

```
public List<System.Func<bool>> conditions = new List<System.Func<bool>>()
{
        bool Iamdead()
        {
        ...
        return ...;
        }
        ,
        bool Iamalive()
        {
        ...
        return ...;
        }
};
```

This gave me parsing error

I tried like that:

```
public List<System.Func<bool>> conditions = new List<System.Func<bool>>()
    {
Iamdead,Iamalive
    };

        static bool Iamdead()
        {
        ...
        return ...;
        }
        static bool Iamalive()
        {
        ...
        return ...;
        }
```

This worked only if the methods are static but I do not want them to be static. Without static, it doesn't work. It seems I couldn't understand the data structure here. Can anyone tell me the correct way of defining Func in a list?

Thanks

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your posts. The code is *really* hard to read at the moment. Additionally "it doesn't work" doesn't give any information.

Comment: Did your original question have methods which always returned `true` or `false` (hard-coded)?  That seems to have caused some confusion in answers...

Comment: Yes, Func returns only true or false but of course the Iamdead, Iamalive methods will have their own calculations other than returning dead, alive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is that you're trying to access `this` (implicitly) within a field initializer. You're not allowed to do that. Just move the initialization into a constructor:

```
// You don't really use public fields, do you?
private readonly List<Func<bool>> conditions;

public MyClass()
{
    conditions = new List<Func<bool>> { Method1, Method2 };
}

private bool Method1() { ... }
private bool Method2() { ... }
```

(I'm assuming you *actually* want your conditions to depend on state within the instance. If they don't, you don't need `this`. If the methods aren't used other than for these conditions, and they're short enough, you might want to use lambda expressions instead.)

Comment: jon can you  explain please what spike  has done  :)

Comment: @KamelBRAHIM: Spike has given an answer which uses lambda expressions which don't depend on `this`. a) the answer doesn't use method group conversions, which is what the OP apparently wanted; b) even using lambda expressions, that will fail to compile as soon as it accesses state within the instance.

Comment: thanks it was important your confirmation as it seems strange to me what he is doing with 2  upvote

Comment: Hi Jon, that is true, I do not need them to be public. But still I couldn't make your structure work. I have the "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property" error

Comment: @sonny: You shouldn't get that with the code I've written, where the initialization isn't *in* a field initializer. Which line is failing, of the code I've presented?

Comment: @JonSkeet I used like "private readonly List<Func<bool>> conditions = new List<Func<bool>> { Method1, Method2 };" and it gave "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property" error. However I got it is wrong use. And I used directly how it is stated on your comment and I have the "Class, struct, or interface method must have a return type" error for the public MyClass() line

Comment: @sonny: Does that code look like the code in my answer? No. My answer *specifically says to move the initialization into the constructor* - so why are you still using a field initializer? The `public MyClass` bit is clearly meant to be whatever your class name is (so that it's the constructor) - you hadn't told us that, so I couldn't give you the exact code. Please take more care reading and understanding the answer before saying it doesn't work.

Comment: That is true, I got the initializer part now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
    public List<System.Func<bool>> conditions = new List<System.Func<bool>>()
                                                    {
                                                        () => false,
                                                        () => true,
                                                    };
```

Comment: That doesn't use any state within the instance. As soon as you try to use a lambda expression which does use state, this will fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use lambdas:

```
public List<System.Func<bool>> conditions = new List<System.Func<bool>>()
{
    () =>
    {
        return false;
    }
    ,
    () =>
    {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: That doesn't use any state within the instance. As soon as you try to use a lambda expression which *does* use state, this will fail to compile.